# Android fingerprint API without lock screen

Tags: android, fingerprint

I want to create an application that would show me some sensitive data only when I authenticate with fingerprint with my Xiaomi mi5.

I took a look to the [Fingerprint sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/FingerprintDialog/src/com.example.android.fingerprintdialog/MainActivity.html) but this requires that I have enabled lock screen with a pattern and a fingerprint.

Is there a way just to use an existing fingerprint without having to configure the fingerprints for the lock screen?

Comment: no it's not possible